# Display information for selected student name from drop down

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to display the corresponding information of a particular
student(from the db) when selecting a particular name in the dropdown.

Here is my code snipet

```
<div  class="col-sm-3">
  <select  class="form-control" ng-model="names" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <option value="">Select Name</option>
    <option ng-repeat="names in stdArray">{{names.Name}}</option>
  </select>
</div> 

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success col-sm-0 style" ng-click="go()">Go</button>
```

Comment: you should use `value={{names.Name}}` and what you tried for server side ?

Comment: use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` of options + `ng-model="propertyToWhichYouWouldLikeToBindTheSelectedStudent"`, not the list itself

Comment: Ok now i have changed my code like this<div  class="col-sm-3">
<select  class="form-control" ng-model="year" ng-options="name.year for name in stdArray | unique: 'year' " >
  <option value="">Select Year</option>
</select>
</div>
<div  class="col-sm-3">
<select  class="form-control" ng-model="branch"  type="button" ng-options="name.Branch for name in stdArray | unique: 'Branch' " >
  <option value="">Select Branch</option>
</select>
</div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success col-sm-0 style" ng-click="go()">Go</button>